# Buscar dato en sql y mostrarlo en grid

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net

Estoy intentando buscar productos desde la base de datos y mostrarlos en una `grid`. El código ejecuta la búsqueda pero no arroja ningún valor.

En la base de datos tengo lo siguiente:

```
create proc [dbo].[spbuscararticulo_venta_codigo]
@textobuscar varchar(50)
as
select d.iddetalle_ingreso,a.Codigo,a.Nombre,
c.nombre as Categoria,p.nombre as Presentacion,
d.stock_actual,d.precio_compra,d.precio_venta,
d.fecha_vencimiento
from articulo a inner join categoria c
on a.idcategoria=c.idcategoria
inner join presentacion p
on a.idpresentacion=p.idpresentacion
inner join detalle_ingreso d
on a.idarticulo=d.idarticulo
inner join ingreso i
on d.idingreso=i.idingreso
where a.codigo=@textobuscar
and d.stock_actual>0
and i.estado<>'ANULADO'
```

en mi botón:

```
//Método BuscarNombre
    private void MostrarArticulo_Venta_Nombre()
    {
        this.dataListado.DataSource = NVenta.MostrarArticulo_Venta_Nombre(this.txtBuscar.Text);
        this.OcultarColumnas();
        lblTotal.Text = "Total de Registros: " + Convert.ToString(dataListado.Rows.Count);
    }
```

al doble clic:

```
private void dataListado_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FrmVenta form = FrmVenta.GetInstancia();
    string par1, par2;
    decimal par3, par4;
    int par5;
    DateTime par6;
    par1 = Convert.ToString(this.dataListado.CurrentRow.Cells["iddetalle_ingreso"].Value);
    par2 = Convert.ToString(this.dataListado.CurrentRow.Cells["nombre"].Value);
    par3 = Convert.ToDecimal(this.dataListado.CurrentRow.Cells["precio_compra"].Value);
    par4 = Convert.ToDecimal(this.dataListado.CurrentRow.Cells["precio_venta"].Value);
    par5 = Convert.ToInt32(this.dataListado.CurrentRow.Cells["stock_actual"].Value);
    par6 = Convert.ToDateTime(this.dataListado.CurrentRow.Cells["fecha_vencimiento"].Value);
    form.setArticulo(par1, par2, par3, par4, par5, par6);
    this.Hide();
}
```

clase Nventa:

```
public static DataTable MostrarArticulo_Venta_Nombre(string textobuscar)
        {
            DVenta Obj = new DVenta();
            return Obj.MostrarArticulo_Venta_Nombre(textobuscar);
        }
```

otra clase, esta es llamada por `Nventas` en otra capa

```
//Mostrar Artículos por su nombre
public DataTable MostrarArticulo_Venta_Nombre(String TextoBuscar)
{
    DataTable DtResultado = new DataTable("articulos");
    SqlConnection SqlCon = new SqlConnection();
    try
    {
        SqlCon.ConnectionString = Conexion.Cn;
        SqlCommand SqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlCmd.Connection = SqlCon;
        SqlCmd.CommandText = "spbuscararticulo_venta_nombre";
        SqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        SqlParameter ParTextoBuscar = new SqlParameter();
        ParTextoBuscar.ParameterName = "@textobuscar";
        ParTextoBuscar.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
        ParTextoBuscar.Size = 50;
        ParTextoBuscar.Value = TextoBuscar;
        SqlCmd.Parameters.Add(ParTextoBuscar);

        SqlDataAdapter SqlDat = new SqlDataAdapter(SqlCmd);
        SqlDat.Fill(DtResultado);

    }
```

La `grid` se me ordena según a consulta, pero no me muestra nada (y sí tengo valores en base de datos).

Lo extraño es que tengo funciones y cases parecidas que cambian en nombre y funcionan pero aquí no veo el error.

Comment: Deberías de aportar más datos y no sólo un montón de código y decir que no te sale nada. Depura la aplicación paso a paso para ver si se forma correctamente la query, si los datos recibidos son los esperados porque ejecutando la consulta hay respuesta desde la BD usando otra forma de atacarla, cómo se desarrolla el enlace con el grid. Así podrás decirnos dónde está exactamente el problema para arreglar y será más fácil ayudarte.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El hecho que no devuelva resultados puede ser causado por varios puntos que deberias validar.

Lo primero que noto es que en el codigo defines `spbuscararticulo_venta_nombre` pero el procedure se llama `spbuscararticulo_venta_codigo`, esta claro que el nombre es diferente, como primer paso seria validar que invocas al procedure correcto.

Porque tanto codigo para ejecutar la consulta

```
public DataTable MostrarArticulo_Venta_Nombre(String TextoBuscar)
{
    using(SqlConnection SqlCon = new SqlConnection(Conexion.Cn))
    {
        SqlCommand SqlCmd = new SqlCommand("spbuscararticulo_venta_codigo",SqlCon);
        SqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@textobuscar", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = TextoBuscar;

        SqlDataAdapter SqlDat = new SqlDataAdapter(SqlCmd);
        DataTable DtResultado = new DataTable();
        SqlDat.Fill(DtResultado);

        return DtResultado;
    }
}
```

como veras se puede reducir, no definas un try..catch en ese codigo, atrapa el problema en capas superiores cuando llegue a la UI, ademas usa el `using` para definir el bloque de la conexion, si haras que el pooling de ado.net mantenga la instancia de la conexion.

La query que defiens en el procedure tiene muchos INNER JOIN, cualquier relacion que no tenga datos podria causar que no devuelva registros, debes validar los datos que usas ejecutando el SELECT en el management studio para validar que todos los join estan correctos.

Si es una busqueda por proximacion y el texto ingresado no es completo deberias usar el LIKE

```
where a.codigo LIKE '%' + @textobuscar + '%'
```

de esta forma encontraras registros aunque no ingreses el codigo coincidente en todo su contenido.